# zsh alias dropping first character at execution

Tags: zsh, alias

Okay, so my alias is `alias pinecalcmanj="scp ~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics $pinemanjaro:~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar_computer.ics"`. Running the alias in a command line, I see `cp: cannot create regular file ':~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar_computer.ics': No such file or directory`. If I copy and paste the alias contents into the command line, it runs fine. It seems that the first character in the alias is dropped in the execution.

Here's the interesting rub, though. I added a white space before the 's' and executed the alias, giving the new alias, `alias pinecalcmanj=" scp ~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics $pinemanjaro:~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar_computer.ics"`. Hey presto, it worked. Great. I saved the alias with the space behind it.

Well, the next time I went to use the alias it didn't work, seeing the same issue, that the 's' wasn't recognised. I removed the white space, saved the zshrc, and ran the alias and it worked. So, it seems that every time I want to use the alias, I need to open the zshrc and either remove a white space or add one in order for it to work. I am very confused here. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the `s` is being eaten; I suspect that `scp` is just replacing itself with `cp`, so `cp` is actually producing the error.

Comment: (The difference you are seeing is based on `pinemanjaro` being defined *after* the alias is define in `.zshrc` but *before* you redefine the alias at the command line.)

Comment: Interesting @chepner. The alias is defined before the variable`$pinemanjaro` in the actual .zshrc script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'll work if you replace double quotes by single quotes, like this:

```sh
alias pinecalcmanj='scp ~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics $pinemanjaro:~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar_computer.ics'
```

The reason is single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will.
Here is what the Bash manual says:

- [Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
- [Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)

Comment: Along with this, I wonder if `scp` just execs `cp` when it has two local paths, which would lead to the appearance that the `s` is being "eaten" in the resulting error message.

Comment: @chepner, it would seem so. The fact that that the single quote line works suggests to be that zsh was assuming that the `$pinemanjaro:~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar_computer.ics` was a local path. I feel like I'm really learning something about the shell here.

Comment: Well, `:~/.local/share...` is the local path, produced when `$pinemanjaro` expands to the empty string when it is undefined. (`:~` is a legal directory name.)